# Syntax of if loop inside a for loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

for the following table data in @details array variable

```
company       location    departmet    team
  hp          delhi        hr           t1 
  ibm         mumbai       tech         t1
  hp          banglore     tech         t2
```

how to get the location if company is 'hp'?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: all your ruby variables must be enclosed by <% or <%=, and %>, including statements and closing 'end's

Comment: sorry for not following proper format.am new to ruby environment.want to know  for loop and if loop implementation in ruby.the following answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will  be just:

```
<% @details.each do |detail| %>
  <% if detail.company == 'hp' %>
    <%=detail.location %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or if there is only one condition:

```
<% @details.each do |detail| %>
  <%=detail.location if detail.company == 'hp' %>
<% end %>
```